# how to get a json result for python scraping

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to learn Python scraping and I want to get the categories and sub-categories from a site and put them in a json file. can you let me know how to do it? I really appreciate it. thank you so much in advance.

```
 import BeautifulSoup
 import os
 import urllib
 from urllib.request import urlopen , urlretrieve
 from datetime import datetime as dt
 import os.path
 import json
    
 cats_name=[]
    
 sub_cats_name = []
    
 theUrl = 'https://divar.ir/s/tehran'
    
 for j in range(1,3):
     result = requests.get(theUrl.format(j))
     resultc =result.content
     print(result.text)
    
 sp = BeautifulSoup(result.text ,'html.parser')
 print(sp.prettify())

 cut_soup1 = sp.findAll('ul', attrs={'class':'kt-accordion'})
 cut_soup2 = sp.findAll('li', attrs ={"kt-accordion-item kt-accordion-item--with-icon kt-accordion-item_header"})

 for i in range(0,len(cut_soup1)):
     cats_name.append(cut_soup1[i].text)
     sub_cats_name.append(cut_soup2[i].text)
     print("categories: ".format(j), cats_name ," sub-cats: " + sub_cats_name)
```

Comment: Is your question "How do I find specific things on a web page", or "How do I save things in a json file"?

Answer (score 1):

This is what Scrapy is doing:

https://scrapy.org/